# How to show textbox values in Grid

Tags: javascript, gridview, extjs, row, addition

i am newbie in extjs , i want to add row in grid when i click a button , my form has three textbox name , id--name--age , and i have a grid with three columns id--name--age , now i want to add value of textbox id in column id , value of textbox name in column name , and value of age in textbox age. now i have no idea how to perform this ,please help me to resolve this , as i have experience in vb.net and c#  there is a property of grid called rows.add , in js is there any property like rows.add to add rows in grid.

please help me as i am newbie .

Best Regards,

M.Waqas Aslam

Answer (score 1):

see this, it seems exactly what your need http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/writer/writer.html